# I am having an error which i dont have any idea about and dont know how to solve it

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-widget

I created a class which shows a loading spinner and cancel loading spinner and when I call the `CustomFullScreenLoadingDialog.showLoaderDialog()` after my try it works fine but after a login success I call `CustomFullScreenLoadingDialog.cancelDialog()` to remove that spinner after success but i am getting this error

> Failed assertion: line 5036 pos 12: '!_debugLocked': is not true.

Need some helpful insight please,
I am stuck in this problem

This is my class.

```dart
class CustomFullScreenLoadingDialog {
  static void showLoaderDialog(BuildContext context) async {
    AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
      content: Row(
        children: [
          const CircularProgressIndicator(),
          Container(
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 7),
              child: const Text("Loading Store...")),
        ],
      ),
    );
    showDialog(
      barrierDismissible: false,
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return alert;
      },
    );
  }

  static Future<void> cancelDialog(BuildContext context) async {
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }
}
```

This is the place where I called the spinner and how I called it when trying I call that spinner and after a success and I am navigated to home-screen I want to remove that loading spinner but I am getting that error

```dart
try{
    CustomFullScreenLoadingDialog.showLoaderDialog(context);
    final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url),
        headers:<String,String>{
      'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
    }
    );
    final responseData = jsonDecode(response.body);
    if(response.statusCode == 200){
      print('Login Successes');
      Navigator.of(context).pushReplacementNamed('Home-Screen');
      CustomFullScreenLoadingDialog.cancelDialog(context);
    }
```

Comment: Does it work  by commenting `Navigator` ?

Comment: no it doesnt but i solved this problem by using easyloading package sorry for the troble